# Waiting for Scene repaint

Tags: java, events, javafx

Is there any possible way to wait for the scene to repaint?

My problem is, that i want to add a Note to a Pane with getChildren().add() and then to fire an event on this Node with Node.fireEvent(event).

But the event is not performed. I think the problem is, that the scene was not repainted at the point of the fireevent and so the Node is not a part of the new Scene at this time.

So the best way would be to wait for the scene to repaint and then fire the event i think.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which is the UI Component you has been used here, but, try to find out the invalidate() method (or something like that) of your component to make it update the screen after all.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post code? This works fine for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewNodeEventTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox(5);
        Button newNodeButton = new Button("Add button");
        newNodeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Button newButton = new Button("Button");
            newButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("New button pressed"));
            root.getChildren().add(newButton);
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(newButton, newButton);
            newButton.fireEvent(evt);
        });
        root.getChildren().add(newNodeButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```